# Can't show an observable array's item in a <div>

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

hi I am new in KnockOut and try to do some simple code with it,but i have a problem in showing my observable array items in a div,it seems easy,i use F12 and trace my array,my add function is working but i dont know why i can't show array items in a div,thanks for help.

here is my code:view

```
    <div class="panel panel-info">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Items Here" data-bind='value:items, valuupdate:"afterkeydown"'>
          <span class="input-group">
              <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click:add">ADD</button> 
          </span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <label>Your Items</label>
        <div  data-bind="foreach:addeditems">
            <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:addeditems().length"></span>
        </div>

        <!--<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" data-bind="text:addeditems"></textarea>-->
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible:addeditems().length>0">golnaz</div>
</div>
```

and this is my viewModel:

```
 define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'AddItems';
    var items = ko.observable("");
    var addeditems = ko.observableArray("");
    var add = function () {
        return addeditems().push(items());
    };

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: title,
        items: items,
        addeditems: addeditems,
        add:add
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

but i can't see items or even the length of the array.
thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addeditems()` is not a property of "addeditems". You are in a loop with the scope being `addeditems`. Try `$root.addeditems().length` instead. Note that this will show the length of the entire array for each element in the array.

Also, you  may also want to reconsider your VM initialization:

`var addeditems = ko.observableArray("")` should be `var addeditems = ko.observableArray([])`. The default value of an observableArray should be an empty array, not an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Don't get the underlying array when calling `add`.

```
var add = function () {
    return addeditems.push(items());
};
```

Also don't do that in your view.

Comment: @ Daniel A. thank u so much for answering me it now shows the item in div but only show the first item of the array and still dose not show the length of the array but when i press F12 i see that items are added in my array but just the first item showed in  a div

Comment: thank u so much for answering me it now shows the item in div but only show the first item of the array and still dose not show the length of the array but when i press F12 i see that items are added in my array but just the first item showed